# apply() when function depends on index and mutate() efficiency

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, tidyr

I was wondering, suppose you want to transform some matrix, for example, and you want something like

```
Y[i,j] = i*j*X[i,j]
```

Using a for loop is a lot slower than other options, and apply() doesn't know which i and j it is using.

A solution I can think of is defining a data.frame-like object with columns i,j,X and then use mutate() to get the desired Y values.

I have two questions:

(a) Is it possible to construct the above matrix using apply() instead of a for loop? If there is, is it more efficient to construct it this way, or   using the mutate() trick?

(b) Assume I have both matrix and data.frame object representations. Which is more efficient if I want to do operations that include row and col index? For example, if want a statistic like the sum of (Y[i,j] - mean(Y))²/(i*j). I know I can construct matrices with the row and col indexes and then just use vectorized functions, but is it better than using mutate?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how large and sparse your matrix is, the first thing you may give a try is use `row` and `col` function to construct `row` and `column` indices respectively, and then use it to transform your matrix:

```
X <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)

row(X) * col(X) * X
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    8   21
#[2,]    4   20   48
#[3,]    9   36   81
```

---

Then for `(Y[i,j] - mean(Y))²/(i*j)`, it's similarly:

```
Y <- row(X) * col(X) * X
(Y - mean(Y)) ^ 2 / (row(Y) * col(Y))

#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] 592.11111 150.222222   6.259259
#[2,] 227.55556   7.111111  85.629630
#[3,]  88.92593  18.962963 344.308642
```

<sub>This is fully vectorized approach, requiring no `apply` or `for loop` but need additional memory.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I think `outer` may be faster that `row(X) * col(X)`.

```
# Define dimensions
n.rows <- n.cols <- 1000

# Define matrix
X <- matrix(runif(n.rows * n.cols), ncol = n.cols)

# Psidom's approach
rowcol.method <- function(X){row(X) * col(X) * X}

# Approach using outer
outer.method <- function(X){outer(1:nrow(X), 1:ncol(X)) * X}

# Benchmark library
library(microbenchmark)

# Test
microbenchmark(
  rowcol.method(X),
  outer.method(X)
)
```

**Results:**

```
Unit: milliseconds
             expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 rowcol.method(X) 20.895870 21.154815 23.795695 21.612485 22.584323 62.50660   100   b
  outer.method(X)  5.608577  5.729724  6.883643  5.836526  5.977156 50.12508   100  a
```

**Compare output:**

```
identical(rowcol.method(X), outer.method(X))
[1] TRUE
```

---

Similarly for the other calculation, although there was a crazy outlier for the outer approach (221.66718 ms).

```
# Define matrix
Y <- row(X) * col(X) * X

# Psidom's approach
rowcol.method.Y <- function(Y) {(Y - mean(Y)) ^ 2 / (row(Y) * col(Y))}

# Approach using outer
outer.method.Y <- function(Y) {(Y - mean(Y)) ^ 2 / outer(1:nrow(X), 1:ncol(X))}

# Test
microbenchmark(
  rowcol.method.Y(Y),
  outer.method.Y(Y)
)
```

**Results:**

```
Unit: milliseconds
               expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
 rowcol.method.Y(Y) 27.94405 30.18635 34.63551 33.32627 37.06467  46.58983   100   b
  outer.method.Y(Y) 11.27064 12.66349 18.77192 15.66756 18.18864 221.66718   100  a
```

**Compare output:**

```
identical(rowcol.method.Y(Y), outer.method.Y(Y))
[1] TRUE
```